# Kivy runs but, does not open window

Tags: python, kivy

I try to run a simple Kivy application. Everything seems ok but, the window does not open. Why window does not open?

```
 import kivy
 kivy.require('1.11.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.label import Label


 class MyApp(App):

     def build(self):
         return Label(text='Hello world')


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyApp().run()
```

When I run it gives this output:
**

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\*\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-02-26_16.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
```

**

Comment: How does "mobile-application" tie into this? You seem to be running on Windows, right?

Comment: What are you doing to run it?

Comment: > python main.py